# Send image for android Java WebServer Rest

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have the following code in my web service

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
) {

try {
    saveToDisk(uploadInputStream, fileDetail);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UsuarioFacadeREST.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     return "Erro ao enviar arquivo";
}

return "yes";
}

private void saveToDisk(InputStream uploadedInputStream, FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws FileNotFoundException {

String uploadedFileLocation = ValidaCampos.retornaCaminhoImg() + File.separator;

try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));

    while((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes))!=-1)
    {
    out.write(bytes,0,read);

    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
      Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    logger.info("ERRO AO FAZER UPLOAD "+ ex.getMessage());
}
}}
```

In android I have the following caught a photo

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    System.out.println(photo);

        intermediario(String.valueOf(photo));
}}
```

Doubts as to sending to webservice? how to call this class and how to adapt to my webService

```
    public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

private static final String FILE_PART_NAME = "file";
private static final String STRING_PART_NAME = "text";

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File mFilePart;
private final String mStringPart;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener, File file, String stringPart)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    mFilePart = file;
    mStringPart = stringPart;
    buildMultipartEntity();
}

private void buildMultipartEntity()
{
    //entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart));
    try
    {
        entity.addPart(STRING_PART_NAME, new StringBody(mStringPart));
        System.out.println("FOIII");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return entity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        entity.writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response)
{
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}}
```

Upload the need to make a picture for my Webservice save in a folder on the server for both my android application as Web can access the photos

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how to call the MultipartRequest and if my design is correct